# NumLock turned off after Ubuntu start under Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, ubuntu-20.04

When I start Ubuntu 20.04 under Hyper-V of Windows 10 1809
NumLock is turned off.

How to prevent it?

What I tried

- Editing Registry for Kyboard to some magic number - does not work
- Set-VMBios cmdlet is not supported now
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard remember-numlock-state true - does not work
- Can't enter VM BIOS during loading of VM
- There is no BIOS option for VM in Hyper-V now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terrible hearing that, but we still don't have any solution for Gen 2 VM.
For now for solve it you can use only Gen 1 VM.
PS: I hope MS developers team someday found this post and fixed this bug  :)

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://superuser.com/a/1773601/1150410
Quick fix

```
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
if ([console]::NumberLock -eq $false) {
   $WshShell.SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}")
}
```